# With Respect to MVVM Pattern of Google latest architecture guideline, how to pass data(notify) from repository calss to ModelView class

Tags: android, rx-java, observer-pattern, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have developed the sample project with the latest Google Architecture guideline,

I have a fragment.

**MainFragment.kt**

- which receives the data from `MainViewModel` `LiveData` and updates the UI which is working fine

**MainViewModel.kt**

- which has `MutableLiveData<User>` user, whenever I update the user, my Observer in `MainFragment` get called and I'm updating the UI ( working fine)

**Now my question is?**

- in my `MainActivity` I have two fragments loaded, `MainFragment` & `SecondaryFragment`.

  - I have a Repository.kt class which makes API call and get the User data from `SecondFragment.KT`

**Now how do I notify from Repository.kt to MainViewModel that I have latest data to update ?**

- do I need to use `RXJava` to pass the data from `Repository.KT` to `MainViewModel.KT`, in that case how do I use it to pass user data?
- Does Android Latest Architecture do support any observer to accomplish this?

Comment: You need to notify MainFragment about data changes called by SecondFragment? If so, just make your UserRepository as Singleton, and MainFragment subscribed with LiveData to this repository will be notified about data changes.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go by parts:

> Now how do I notify from Repository.kt to MainViewModel that I have
>   latest data to update ?

You can use an observer pattern, just like the one you're using from the MainViewModel to the UI. If your using retrofit you can use a call adapter to return RxJava's Observables (or Singles, Flowables and so on) from your Retrofit calls, so for example you could have something like this:

```
  @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: application/json"})
  @POST("/sign_in")
  Single<Response<LoginResponse>> traditionalLoginUser(
            @Body LoginRequest request,
            @Header("Authorization") String authToken);
```

This is a typical Retrofit interface that returns a Single, you can then observe this single in your repository or simply pass it along to the ViewModel to be observed there.

You can also add a call adapter for LiveData (there's one implemented by google [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/util/LiveDataCallAdapterFactory.kt)) and use LiveData instead of RxJava. I personally don't like to use LiveData for the Network Layer, though.

> do I need to use RXJava to pass the data from Repository.KT to
>   MainViewModel.KT, in that case how do I use it to pass user data?

You can use RxJava, yes. I've actually been working in a sample app that does exactly that. The basic idea is that you use the repository to get the data from your API and pass the Observable along to the ViewModel. What I like to do in the ViewModel is to treat any possible erros by subscribing to the observable (or other rx entity) in there and receiving the data. As we can't necessarily treat erros on LiveData as we do with RxJava we can wrap the LiveData to propagate the error to the view as a state of our wrapper(this is actually found in this google [sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/vo/Resource.kt)).

So for example, in my repository I have this:

```
fun getUsersNotPaged(page: Int, pageSize: Int): Single<SOResponse<User>> {
        return remoteDataSource.apiService.getTopUsers(page, pageSize)

    }
```

Then in my View model I do like this:

```
var userList: MutableLiveData<LiveResource<SOResponse<User>>> = MutableLiveData()

 fun getUserListNotPaged(page: Int, pageSize: Int): MutableLiveData<LiveResource<SOResponse<User>>> {
        val result = usersRepository
                .getUsersNotPaged(page, pageSize)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ result ->
                    userList.postValue(LiveResource(LiveResourceStatus.SUCCESS, result, null))
                }, { error ->
                    userList.postValue(LiveResource(LiveResourceStatus.ERROR, null, error.localizedMessage))
                })


        return userList
    }
```

And in my view:

```
 viewModel.getUserListNotPaged(1, 20).observe(this, Observer {
            it?.data?.let {
                Toast.makeText(this.context, "Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
        })
```

I've used LiveResource to wrap my RxJava response and errors.

You can also use the `ReactiveStrems` extension to convert an Rx `Publisher` into a `LiveData`, but you need to handle the cases when an error happens in the `ViewModel` and guarantee there's no error to the resulting `LiveData`. Something like this:

```
fun getUserListNotPaged(page: Int, pageSize: Int): LiveData<SOResponse<User>> {
        val result = usersRepository
                .getUsersNotPaged(page, pageSize)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .onErrorReturn {
                   SOResponse<User>()
                }
                .toFlowable()

        return LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(result)
    }
```

In this case, whenever there is an error I simply return an empty response.

> Does Android Latest Architecture do support any observer to accomplish
>   this?

Yeah, as you could see you can use `LiveData` all over the place or only half way through the process (from the VM to the UI only). Some people don't agree on using `LiveData` with HTTP calls [though](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2354) (I'm one of them lol).

Comment: Appricate your answer , pretty much clearly explained . if you have any end to end simple example do post it , might be help full for others .

Comment: I have this sample app I'm working on https://github.com/Levi-Moreira/MockAppMVVM I'm about to commit some new changes into it that deal exactly with what we talked about :)

Comment: Thanks for the link , I will go through it , may I get some more clarity n idea 

Comment: Sure, if you need any help just let me know :)

Comment: Yup sure will get back to you .

Comment: Got busy with some other stuff , will check this out .